# Sign in Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

After strictly following the Facebook developer website in order to create Sign in button, I've created everything that needed. However, I was creating an project without fragment,as it's provided in documentation and it seems something went wrong. Here is my Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                }
            });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

The other part is definitely correct. I get such log: 
Log:

```
04-18 02:12:11.348 2781-2781/com.example.vlad.sign2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.example.vlad.sign2, PID: 2781
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vlad.sign2/com.example.vlad.sign2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                      at 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
                                                                      at com.example.vlad.sign2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
                                                                      at com.example.vlad.sign2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30) 
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                   Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
                                                                      at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:145)
                                                                      at com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.<init>(AccessTokenTracker.java:55)
                                                                      at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2.<init>(LoginButton.java:563)
                                                                      at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:563)
                                                                      at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.<init>(FacebookButtonBase.java:69)
                                                                      at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:201)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
                                                                      at com.example.vlad.sign2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30) 
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.vlad.sign2.MainActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />
```

UPDATE:
After adding I get this error:

```
4-18 02:35:45.721 3412-3441/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
                                             Process: com.example.vlad.sign2, PID: 3412
                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:746)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:774)
                                                 at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:846)
                                                 at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:491)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

UPDATE2:String.xml`

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Sign1</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="facebook_app_id">277693549XXXXXX</string>
```

And Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ......

It solve your problem..........

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_fblogin_main);`

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
```

All **FacebookSdk** initialized in `OnResume()` method or before  setContentView(R.layout.content_main) in `OnCreate` method;

Comment: Did you added the facebook id ..??

Comment: <string name="app_id">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string> this line in string.xml

Comment: <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>   and this one in your manifest file

Comment: It was done even before that error, so it didn't help